# Create PDF/DOCX/HTML docs in .NET

Tags: .net, pdf, docx

In the application I am developing, I need to create documents which can be exported to HTML, DOCX or PDF, according to the user's preferences.

How can I do it using only free libraries in a reliable way? I'd rather not to have to generate each document by hand, but use some kind of template (e.g. XSLT)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PDF and HTML (and RTF but not DOCX) there is [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) library.

For Docx there is [Microsoft Office](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124) library.

Answer (score 1):

[open xml sdk 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx)
or
[DocX](http://docx.codeplex.com)

Those are 2 options. Right out off google

Comment: How would I do it for PDF though?

Comment: It is doable, he explains it in a [blogpost](http://cathalscorner.blogspot.com/2009/10/converting-docx-into-doc-pdf-html.html) I haven't tested it yet, but it seems possible

Comment: Not very reliable IMHO, because it is using Word automation